# Access JSON Ajax Response data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have added a property to a JSON data but I cannot access the data on JS it does not show. I am not new to Ajax and JSON but it is a apparent that I still have gaps in my knowledge when it comes to Ajax. Please help me understand how i can append data to my Ajax response.

I have this in a PHP controller class:

```
$x = '5';

if($request->ajax()){
    return response()->json([
        'total_questions' => $x,
        'responseText' => $e->getMessage(), 
    ], 500);
}
```

I want to access the total_questions property with JS/JQuery..

My JS AJAX callback is here:
 console.log('errors -> ', data.total_questions); - returns undefined

```
$.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url: APP_URL+"selfEvaluation/save",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log('data -> ', data);
        console.log('errors -> ', data.total_questions);

        if(data.status == 422){
            // alert('422');
        }
    }
});
```

This is my console result 
[image]

Comment: what are you getting in console.log?

Comment: @Gaurav, check edit

Comment: Can you inlcude what you're getting in your json response.?

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I get undefined

Comment: Double check if your return format is also json or not?

Comment: what is result of `console.log(data);` of this

Comment: @Gaurav that line won't run. OP is looking at the "error" callback, because the server is returning a 500 error (see the PHP snippet).

Comment: Mate I don't know much about Php, but worries me is this line "$(this).serialize()" , if you would console.log this line what would you get?
If your server side php action is not receiveing any params, you can write "data: null".

Comment: @Kadaj `$(this).serialize()` will serialize the form (assuming this code is executed within the context of a form's "submit" event, and send that data to the server. But OP's issue is not with sending data, it's with parsing the response.

Comment: Why are you returning a `500` response code. Thats an error response code

Comment: Clearly there is an error on the server side. You showed only client side code. Like this it is not possible to debug. What is important here is what you are sending to the server, and why the server returns a 422 error.

Comment: Why do you vote down the answers of people helping you? Vote up the good answer!

Comment: replace 500 by 200 to get data in success.

Comment: 422 is a WebDAV related error code (according to Wikipedia, at least). Is WebDAV installed on the server? Maybe remove/disable it and see if that helps. Despite my answer below (which still has validity once you get to that point), I think you need to fix this first. Also, can you post what the ajax request looks like (from your browser's network tab)? Then we could see if there's anything odd about what's being sent to the server. And maybe also show the PHP code which receives and handles the ajax request. At the moment we can only see how you generate the resulting response.

Comment: Hey guys sorry was offline for a bit. tired changing the status code but still no change

Comment: My objective is just to append a variable to the JSON data, when returning it from controller to the JS script - so if there is another way to do this..

Comment: you're having a problem somewhere _before_ the bit where you set the status code. 422 is not being set by you, is it? You were setting 500. So the problem is prior to that part of your code. Look at my comment above and follow the recommendations to try and debug it.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5, 422 status error code happens when using the validate method during an AJAX request,  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation

Comment: Also after a playing around with this i have noticed this: 1. even if I return return response()->json(['lol']);  I still get the standard ajax response callback... question now is can i return a custom variable with the ajax response callback standards to JS script??

Comment: The reason `return response()->json(['lol']);` has no effect is because _you are not generating the repsonse_. Laravel is generating the 422 response for you in a separate process, and providing the response content (which is a list of validation errors). You need to fix the validation problems in the data you're sending before _your_ PHP response code will even run. Once you do that, and it's your code providing the response, you can return _anything you like_ to the ajax "success" response, if you set the status code to 200.

Answer (score 1):

`error: function(data){`

is an incorrect method signature. See the definition at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. 
It should be

`error: function(jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus){`.

You'll need to access the `jqXHR.responseJSON` property. So:

`console.log('errors -> ', jqXHR.responseJSON.total_questions);`

But I would question why you're returning a "500" status code for this request, when it appears to be a valid response. "500" means "Internal Server Error", which implies the server crashed, when it appears that it did not. If you return a "200" ("OK") status, your ajax code will go into the "success" callback and you can directly reference the "data" object in the callback to read your data.

Comment: My objective is just to append a variable to the JSON data, when returning it from controller to the JS script - so if there is another way to do this.

Comment: btw it does not matter if i pass data or jqXHR, .. result is the same.

Comment: it's true that "data" or "jqXHR" are interchangeable, you can choose whatever variable name you like, but I find it's more understandable to follow the jQuery convention - after all, what's in the variable is not your "data" (that's in a child property) but the whole XHR response.

Comment: "My objective is just to append a variable to the JSON data." You've succeeded in that objective, in the sense that the data is there inside the "responseJSON" property when the ajax call returns an error. However, I'm questioning whether returning an error response for this request is appropriate, especially a 500. Also see my comment on the main question above - it seems you have a problem before you even reach this stage in any case, so it's probable your data is _not_ getting appended to the response because it's failing before it gets to the code which adds it.

Comment: I have removed the status codes from the response()-> json(['']); in controller, but still no results

Comment: Also after a playing around with this i have noticed this: 1. even if I return return response()->json(['lol']);  I still get the standard ajax response callback... question now is can i return a custom variable with the ajax response callback standards to JS script??

Answer (score -2):

try this if you will get a json response from your browser.

```
if($request->ajax()){
    $result = array(
        'total_questions' => $x,
        'responseText' => $e->getMessage(), 
    ], 500);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: OP is already getting a response. This is just the way of creating a response without whatever framework they're using. The problem is they can't parse it on the client-side.